# Htaccess remove string from URL

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

We've currently moved our site to a new server but re-formatted the menu item links.

The previous ones were:

```
www.example.com/products/module-home/something.html
```

and now they are:

```
www.example.com/products/something.html
```

What I would like to do is, if a user tried to visit a page which contains `module-home` in the URL, it will simply remove it and redirect them to the URL without it. Would the following RewriteRule rule be the best approach for this?

```
RewriteRule ^module-home/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I know Joomla has it's own redirect manager built into the backend, however performance wise, I think modifying the `.htaccess` file would be better, however correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your htaccess is in the root folder, you can put this rule in first position (right after `RewriteEngine on` or `RewriteBase` line)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/module-home/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Had a little bit of an issue trying to understand the logic. But got it after all. Thanks works great @Justin lurman